# Textbox clashed

Tags: python, tkinter

Created two text boxes and this is how it turned out...

[image: textbox]

Does anyone know how to split it up and place it side-by-side or something?

Here's a clearer picture of what I'm trying to get:

[image: result]

I need to create 3 text boxes...

```
#text box
textbox1 = tk.Text(master=window, height=10, width =30, bg="white")
textbox1.grid(column=1,row=5, columnspan=7, rowspan =500)

textbox2 = tk.Text(master=window, height=10, width =30, bg="white", relief='solid')
textbox2.grid(column=1,row=10, columnspan=7, rowspan =500)
```

Comment: You're using `grid`, which allows you to specify rows and columns. Have you tried changing the row and/or column numbers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using the .grid() method you can use the .place() method.

This geometry manager organizes widgets by placing them in a specific position in the parent widget.

```
#text box
textbox1 = tk.Text(master=window, height=10, width =30, bg="white")
textbox1.place(x = X1, y = Y1)

textbox2 = tk.Text(master=window, height=10, width =30, bg="white", relief='solid')
textbox2.place(x = X2, y = Y2)

#You may assign X1,Y1,X2 and Y2 according to your requirements. They are the Horizontal and vertical offset in pixels.
```

I hope this helped.